# Turn off Chrome new window animation

Tags: macos, terminal, google-chrome, animation

I searched around on google and did find one answer but it seemed as that only worked for Ubuntu. I'm trying to disable the "maximize" effect of chrome when opening a new window. Chrome is the only app that does this and no other app on my mac has a "maximize" animation for a new window and it's bothering me a ton. Is there any way to disable this animation permanently on macOS? It's super annoying.

i tried adding `open /Applications/Chrome.app/ --args --wm-window-animations-disabled` to a exec file and running chrome from there. Chrome opens but the new window "maximize" animation is still there. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://superuser.com/questions/1745621/turn-off-the-new-window-animation-on-chrome-for-macos